# How to debug a recursive directory search script in PHP?

Tags: php, recursion, delete-file, directory

I am trying to delete a folder with everything inside it. But it doesn't seem to be working. I have tried lots of different methods. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php 
$path = $_POST['Name'];
session_start();

$dir = __DIR__ . "$path";
$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$ri = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
foreach ( $ri as $file ) {
    $file->isDir() ?  rmdir($file) : unlink($file);
}

 echo "<h1 style='font:normal;'>The Account $path Was deleted</h1>";


?>
```

Comment: Why not `echo $file;` prior to the deletion to see what you are trying to delete? I seem to recall that these iterators return an array of objects, not an array of strings (they may have a magic toString value, but look at the docs to confirm).

Comment: Also, check the return value on your delete commands - they should return a success boolean. I think your code should stop and report an error if a delete fails.

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution, you could use  [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to find all files matching a certain pattern

```
function RemoveDirectory($direct)
{
    foreach(glob("{$direct}/*") as $file)
    {
        if(is_dir($file)) { 
            RemoveDirectory($file);
        } else {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
    rmdir($direct);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't delete anything for me :(

Comment: Could you show the folder with files, so I can try and repeat the action.

Comment: The directory to the file looks like this /htdocs/Admin/(foldername)

Comment: I tried it with the path doing this `RemoveDirectory("C:\wamp\htdocs\Admin\Chris");` and it worked, are you sure it's the correct folder and that you're using absolute path?

Comment: Doesn't work for me still. The php file is located in the Admin folder. And the path folder is located before admin folder **(../)** is what I used. `RemoveDirectory("../$path")`

Comment: Please try a absolute path so "RemoveDirectory("C:\then rest of path")

Comment: I am using a web hosing service and don't have php installed on this computer. So I can't, you sure there isn't a problem with your code maybe you missed **(;)** on something because at the end of it I have an echo which isn't even working anymore.

Comment: I've tested the code, and I've even put it in a try block, and the try block worked fine. There must be something wrong inside your code which is blocking the deletion of the file. Add a try block in your php and echo out the try block message and see if it gives you an error.